# Django Channels: How to pass incoming messages to external script which is running outside of django?

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis, django-channels

I have started a private project with Django and Channels to build a web-based UI to control the music player daemon (mpd) on raspberry pi. I know that there are other projects like Volumio or moode audio etc. out of the box that is doing the same, but my intension is to learn something new!

Up to now I have managed to setup a nginx server on the pi that communicates with my devices like mobile phone or pc. In the background nginx communicates with an uWSGI server for http requests to Django and a daphne server as asgi for ws connection to Django Channels. As well there is a redis server installed as backend because the Channels Layer needs this. So, on client request a simple html page as UI is served and a websocket connection is established so far.

In parallel I have a separate script as a mpd handler which is wrapped in a while loop to keep it alive, and which does all the stuff with mpd using the python module python-mpd2.

The mpd handler shall get its commands via websocket from the clients/consumers like play, stop etc. and reacts on that. At the same time, it shall send the timeline of the song when a song is playing, let’s say every one second as well via websocket.  I could manage to send frequently data to all connected clients/consumers with `async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)` from outside but I couldn’t find a solution how to pass data/commands coming from the clients via websocket to my separate running mpd handler script.

I read in the docs for Django Channels that it is not recommended to use while loops in the consumers because this will block all the communication – that’s right I have tried this already. Then I tried to receive messages with the command `async_to_sync(channel_layer.receive)('channel_name')` in the mpd handler with a direct connection to a consumer. But this command blocks my mpd handler because it works async although I use `async_to_sync`.

**So, my question:**

Is it possible to pass messages to outside of Django Channels to other scripts with channel own methods? Do you have any suggestion how to solve this maybe with other methods or workarounds? I am looking for a reliable solution.

I gave thoughts to that issue and have some ideas, but I don’t know if this will lead to any solution:

1. **Polling:**
   The clients send frequently messages and requests via websocket to control the mpd and update the UI. In this case no handler would be needed. (I don’t know if this method will generate to much traffic on the websocket and makes it slow. As well, the connection to mpd has to be established frequently and closed again. Don’t know if this works robust.)
2. **Database:**
   Generate a database where consumers and the mpd handler have access to. The consumers write the incoming messages in a database and the mpd handler reads them out and does the job. (Here I don’t know if there will be problems when the consumers and mpd handler try to access the db at the same time.)
3. **Using Queues with multiprocessing module:**
   Consumers passes the messages via a queue to the mpd handler. (Don’t know if this is possible.)
4. **Catching up the messages in redis:**
   Mpd handler listens frequently on redis to catch up the messages. I read that when the Layers are used in common way the groups and channel names are listed on redis only. Messages are passed via redis when the consumers are started as workers. (That would mean that all my consumers must start as background worker, but how?)

I hope you may have a solution to my question. You may realise from my ideas and the question marks involved to solve this problem that I am not an IT expert. As I wrote at the beginning, I have another engineering background and a newbie in this but very interested to learn something new! So please be patient with me when I don’t understand everything immediately.

I hope to read your answers soon and thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst nobody gave an answer to my question, I tried a little bit out some possible options.

I changed the binding of mpd from fix IP to a socket connection and created a mpd_Handler class with some functions/methods like connect to mpd, disconnect, play, pause etc.

This class is imported in Django consumers.py and views.py. Whenever a web client connects to Django or has a new command (like play, skip etc.), the mpd_Handler will perform the command and respond the actual state of mpd like current song metadata.

A second mpd handler which is running outside of Django as a separate script monitors frequently the mpd state to detect any changes. In case of a change at mpd (e.g., the song of web radio stream has changed or the duration time of the song) this handler informs all clients that are connected to Django consumer group with the command `async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)` so that the clients can update their UI.

At the moment it works, and I hope this is a good solution and helps others who have the same problem. Other suggestions are still welcome!

Best regards.